# Making changes to Airflow code and deploy to containers

Tags: docker, airflow

I am a bit confused about the process of Airflow deployment (I am a newbie here).

What I am trying to do is

1. Clone Git repo to local machine https://github.com/apache/airflow
2. Make changes. For example, I would like to put my companies logo to UI (browser level)
3. Build the code and generate a docker image
4. Push to container registry (Azure for my case)
5. Run services

I am using a Windows machine and Docker Desktop installed.

I have tried the installation in local docker using official help https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The steps you pointed out are proper way to solve your case. Once you have your custom image it can be deployed as any other docker container. I would also suggest cloning the repo and setting your CI/CD pipelines to automate building the image and pushing it to container registry.

Additionally check this [building custom image](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html) and [production deployment](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/production-deployment.html) docs.

Comment: Hi Tomasz, I created a pipeline to automate image creation and able run the pipeline (Build&Push) image with no errors. Now, I am trying to run my webserver as an app and scheduler inside a container(instance). Can I do it ? Please suggest.

Comment: To run them in same container you need to run `airflow scheduler -D` and `airflow webserver -D`. This will trigger both scheduler and webserver as background processes

Comment: I have captured the steps that I am trying to do in a doc. Please let me know your comments. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wAEgxL2XYXDEkJ9ftjN6_skHCi7hvfxD/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106769100098017982691&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: When I hover on the *"Command Override"* option, I see the info: **"The first command to execute within the container. Separate each command with a comma and a space as seen in the example. If you're using values that contain sensitive information like passwords in the command override field, it's recommended that you use a secure environment variable to get it into the container instead, and reference the container."**

Comment: `bash -c "airflow scheduler -D; airflow webserver -D"` looks good

Comment: Looks like it is attempting to run commands. I am seeing this error. **airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: error: cannot use sqlite with the LocalExecutor** full stacktrace is at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lwVP8ByXoXjk9iJNRM9v4u4s1VT56ROg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok. I got the reason for the error. Have set to the SEQUENTIAL executor (default). Error is not there but not seeing Webserver running.

Comment: I need db init part also. Without that command, I saw some missing table errors. then I updated command to **[ "/bin/bash", "-c", "airflow db init ; airflow scheduler -D ; airflow webserver -D" ]**. But only DB init is getting executed but not server and scheduler

Comment: Try, replace `;` with `&`. And I would recommend to never use SQLite in production.  SequencialExecutor is not meant to be production grade.